# How to use WCF with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I just recently started to experiment with .NET MVC 4.

The thing is I have a WCF service that provides data for several application and would like to use it for a site using MVC as well.

Im totally new to this, so Im wondering where the best place to connect to the WCF is. I guess that the WCF could be considered to be the model, and in that case the best way would be to place it in a controller.

But is this really correct or should the service be consumed in the model layer?

Comment: If you're new to MVC/WFC you might want to review http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to architect this using a repository pattern where the repository methods return instances of my model classes:

Inside my controller I will simply instantiate a reference to my repository and call the appropriate methods. The repository will wrap the WCF service proxy and call the service(s) inside the various repository methods

EX from CustomerController:

```
Customer c = customerRepository.GetCustomerById(int customerId)
```

I also tend to have my repositories implement an interface to make it easy to mock the data access layer without having to call external dependencies like the WCF service/database (unit tests)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to keep a seperate `Service Layer` to handle this. The classes in this service layer will interact with other datasource ( WCF service/ Other Repositary / ADO.NET layer etcc) and convert those domain objects to corresponding ViewModels and return those to my Controller Actions when they need it.

```
namespace YourProject.Services
{
 public class UserService
 {

  public UserViewModel GetUser(int id)
  {
    UserViewModel objVM=new UserViewModel();

    User objRealUser=GetUserFromWCFService(id);
   if(objUser.IsValid)
   {
      objVM.FirstName=objUser.FirstName;
      // Assign the other properties to the View model or use Automapper.
   }
   return objVM;
  }    

 }
}
```